# Django: get unique object list from QuerySet

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following (simplified) models in my Django app:

```
class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, blank=True, null=True)

class Favorite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

I'm currently getting all the items I need using the following query:

```
favorites = Favorite.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

**How can I get all the distinct colors for the items in that `QuerySet`?**

I need the a list of the actual color objects, not just the color ids, which I can get using

```
favorites.values_list('item__color').distinct
```

Comment: What's `request` in `request.user`??

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the following should do the trick:

```
favorites = Favorite.objects.filter(user=request.user)
color_ids = favorites.values_list('item__color', flat=True).distinct()
colors = Color.objects.filter(id__in=color_ids)
```

There has to be a cleaner way than that though.

**Edit:** A much cleaner solution:

```
colors = Color.objects.filter(item__favorite__user=request.user).distinct()
```

Comment: +1 thanks. the real original query was actually much more complicated than `user=request.user` so ended up going with the first part of your answer.

Answer (score 8):

Can you do:

```
Color.objects.filter(item__favorite__user = request.user).distinct()
```

You might have to set some `related_name`s on your foreign keys if these aren't the defaults (I can never remember the defaults).

Comment: +1 thanks (the cleaned up query above/below has the correct syntax).

Answer (score 8):

Can you do:

```
favorites = Favorite.objects.filter(user=request.user).distinct('item__color')
```

Comment: perfect and clean solution

Comment: Works only in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

The is `values_list(*fields, flat=False, named=False)` method, so run it on your objects, for example:

```
user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True)
```