# Django - joining multiple tables (models) and filtering out based on their attribute

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm new to django and ORM in general, and so have trouble coming up with query which would join multiple tables.

I have 4 Models that need joining - `Category`, `SubCategory`, `Product` and `Packaging`, example values would be:

`Category: 'male'`

`SubCategory: 'shoes'`

`Product: 'nikeXYZ'`

`Packaging: 'size_36: 1'`

Each of the Model have FK to the model above (ie. `SubCategory` has field `category` etc).

My question is - how can I filter `Product` given a `Category` (e.g. male) and only show products which have `Packaging` attribute `available` set to `True`? Obviously I want to minimise the hits on my database (ideally do it with 1 SQL query).

I could do something along these lines:

```
available = Product.objects.filter(packaging__available=True)
subcategories = SubCategory.objects.filter(category_id=<id_of_male>)
products = available.filter(subcategory_id__in=subcategories)
```

but then that requires 2 hits on database at least (`available`, `subcategories`) I think. Is there a way to do it in one go?

Comment: What about something like this: 

Product.objects.filter(packaging__available=True,subcategories__category_id__in=[id_of_male]) - it isn't tested but I think that subcategories should be plural (related_name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
lookup = {'packaging_available': True, 'subcategory__category_id__in': ['ids of males']}
product_objs = Product.objects.filter(**lookup)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to read:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590692/django-get-unique-object-list-from-queryset)
You can query with _set, multi __ (to link models by FK) or create list ids

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work but it's not tested:

```
Product.objects.filter(packaging__available=True,subcategori‌​es__category_id__in=‌​[id_of_male])
```

- it isn't tested but I think that subcategories should be plural (related_name), if you didn't set `related_name`, then `subcategory__set` instead od `subcategories` should work.

Probably `subcategori‌​es__category_id__in=‌​[id_of_male]` can be switched to `.._id=id_of_male`.